# Sharepoint 2010 list - post save redirection

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

In order to implement certain customization, a lot of custom code has been added to PresaveItem();
This somehow has affected the usual redirection from newform.aspx/editform.aspx .
whenever I try to add/edit an item (irrespective from any view) , onclick of the Save/Cancel button,
it gets returned to the default view.
I tried getting back to the calling page using the code below:

```
$.(document).ready(function(){
 var targerUrl=document.referrer;
if(!PresaveItem()) return false;
 window.location.href=targetUrl;
});
```

This works but the PreSaveItem() dosent get fired.

Putting it together:
There are say 4 views of my list; ViewA.aspx,Viewb.aspx, ViewC,aspx(default).
 If I add a new Item from from ViewA , the newitem.aspx opens, I enter information and click Save.
I get returned to ViewC.aspx . I should have got returned to ViewA.aspx.
Is there any way it implement this? I am using SP2010

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

In Context Menu, we can add a query string parameter as: ?source=source
That solved the problem. This is for anybody who faces problem in redirecting to the source page after save and considering the newitwm/edititem page is opened from context menu. Happy coding!! :)